# Why 0 is true but false is 1 in the shell?

Tags: shell, boolean

```
false; echo $?
```

The above will output `1`, which is contradictory with all other programming languages I know.

Any reason in this?

Comment: It's also in line with the Unix Way... don't return anything on success.

Comment: Because an exit status is not a boolean. Simple as that.

Comment: Keep in mind that `false` is not a boolean, as in other programming languages. It's just a program located at `/bin/false` (`/usr/bin/false` on a Mac) that's meant to always return an error exit code 1. Similar for `true`. So there's no such thing as casting here. It's just all about exit codes.

Comment: A shell is a (user) interface to an operating system. **Unix etc. programs follow the convention of exiting with 0 as OK,** for the reason given in the answers (ability to communicate more than one failure reason). The shell simply keeps this convention, which makes constructs like `if myprog; then echo OK; fi` easy and intuitive. Otherwise you would have to invert every test for success of a program!

Answer (score 112):

Bash is a programming (scripting) language, but it's also a shell and a user-interface.  If `0` was error, then the program could only present one kind of error.

However in Bash, any nonzero value is an error, and we may use any number from 1-255 to represent an error. This means we can have many different kinds of errors. `1` is a general error, `126` means that a file cannot be executed, `127` means 'command not found', etc. Here's a list of Bash [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF) showing some of the most common exit codes.

There are also many kinds of success (exit status is `0`). However, a success will allow you to proceed to the next step—you can like print results to a screen, or execute a command, etc.

Comment: And just for the fun of it, I'll point out that [`/usr/include/sysexits.h` notes exit values](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits) that are perhaps more aspirational, even though the convention they represent dates back to the 1980s. This convention exists outside the scope of bash.

Comment: *"If `0` was error, then the program could only present one kind of error"*.  This statement is key and the reason why this answer should be at the top.

Comment: The ABS link is not correctly labelled; many of the exit codes there are not actually "reserved" and it's not even clear what that is supposed to mean. As always, we advise caution when visiting the so-called Adbvanced Bash Scripting Guide.

Comment: What happens if I return an error code greater than 255?

Comment: @LuisLavaire That is undefined behavior. In practice, the number tends to get truncated; but it would definitely not be "more wrong" if the runtime generated a warning and/or simply crashed. The OS reserved exactly one byte for this information and attempting to put more than one byte there is definitely an error. But the OS designers probably ran into crashes on the first day, and shrugged, and decided that the best they can do is to just truncate the value and move on.

Comment: Using `mksh`, `f () { return 356; }; f; echo $?` shows `100`.

Comment: That is the most common way to truncate it, yes; but as with any undefined behavior, that's probably implementation-dependent, and could change tomorrow.

Answer (score 106):

It's a convention, but a particularly useful one when you think about it.  In general, if a program succeeds that's all you need to know. If it fails, however, you might need to know all kinds of information about the failure - why it happened, how to fix it, etc.  Having zero mean 'success' and non-zero mean failure lets you can check pretty easily for success, and investigate the particular error for more details if you want to.  A lot of APIs and frameworks have a similar convention - functions that succeed return 0 and and those that fail give back an error code describing the particular failure case.

Comment: I understand this answer, but I still don't get why bool to int conversion is inverted. Is there a "return boolean convention" that says: if you return true, it means there is no errors, if you return false, it means an error occured (like the "integer = error code convention" that is more well known)?

Comment: Assuming there is a boolean to int conversion implies that you didn't really understand the answer. Zero means success and all of 1, 2, ..., 255 are error codes which can usefully communicate different failure scenarios. A particular example is `xargs` which uses different error codes in the range around 127 to indicate how a *group* of commands failed. The conversion which can be done is int to bool where 0 maps to success (which I guess you want to express as true / 1; but realize that this is just another arbitrary convention) and all other values to failure.

Comment: Return code could mean Error code, and hence 0 (False) could mean no error, that way True = 1, and False = 0. The concept of error codes to Boolean values does not have to be tied to me?

Answer (score 35):

**There are two related issues here.**

First, the OP's question, *Why 0 is true but false is 1 in the shell?* and the second, *why do applications return 0 for success and non-zero for failure?*

To answer the OP's question we need to understand the second question. The numerous answers to this post have described that this is a convention and have listed some of the niceties this convention affords. Some of these niceties are summarized below.

**Why do applications return 0 for success and non-zero for failure?**

Code that invokes an operation needs to know two things about the exit status of the operation. *Did the operation exit successfully?* [*1] And if the operation does not exit successfully *why did the operation exit unsuccessfully?* Any value could be used to denote success. But 0 is more convenient than any other number because it is portable between platforms. Summarizing xibo's answer to this [question](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=25719) on 16 Aug 2011:

> Zero is encoding-independent.
>
> If we wanted to store one(1) in a 32-bit integer word, the first question would be "big-endian word or little-endian word?", followed by "how long are the bytes composing a little-endian word?", while zero will always look the same.
>
> Also it needs to be expected that some people cast errno to char or short at some point, or even to float. (int)((char)ENOLCK) is not ENOLCK when char is not at least 8-bit long (7-bit ASCII char machines are supported by UNIX), while (int)((char)0) is 0 independent of the architectural details of char.

Once it is determined that 0 will be the return value for success, then it makes sense to use any non-zero value for failure. This allows many [exit codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) to answer the question why the operation failed.

**Why 0 is true but false is 1 in the shell?**

One of the fundamental usages of shells is to automate processes by scripting them. Usually this means invoking an operation and then doing something else conditionally based on the exit status of the operation. [Philippe A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393262/philippe-a) explained nicely in his answer to this post that

> In bash and in unix shells in general, return values are not boolean.
>   They are integer exit codes.

It's necessary then to interpret the exit status of these operations as a boolean value. It makes sense to map a successful (`0`) exit status to true and any non-zero/failure exit status to false. Doing this allows conditional execution of chained shell commands.

Here is an example `mkdir deleteme && cd $_ && pwd`. Because the shell interprets 0 as true this command conveniently works as expected. If the shell were to interpret 0 as false then you'd have to invert the interpreted exit status for each operation.

In short, it would be nonsensical for the shell to interpret 0 as false given the convention that applications return 0 for a successful exit status.

---

[*1]: Yes, many times operations need to return more than just a simple success message but that is beyond the scope of this thread.

See also [Appendix E](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF) in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide

Comment: Hello,

Just to stress that, if the shell were interpreting zero as false and non-zero as true, the trick of doing `mkdir deleteme && cd _$ && pwd` would not really fail; but we would have to replace it by `mkdir deleteme || cd _$ || pwd`, which in my opinion is far less clear, because what we actually want to do is `mkdir deleteme` “_and_” `cd _$` “_and_” `pwd`... (with “and” having here its meaning from ordinary language).

Comment: I think I covered that in my answer. To be clear though, when you invert the logic it is not enough to just replace the `&&` operators with `||` operators. You would need to fully apply De Morgan's law. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Another consideration: I see at least three reasons why, on a general basis, it would be natural to state that `true` corresponds to zero and `false` corresponds to nonzero. First, if I tell you something, “having told you the truth” depends on the number of lies that I have told: either it is zero and I have told (globally) the truth, or it is nonzero and I have lied. This is essentially the same of wanting the logical `and` to correspond to the common “and” of addition (when restricting to natural numbers, obviously).

Comment: (continued from previous comment). Second reason is that there is one truth but many non-truths; so, it is more convenient to associate a sole value for `true` and all other values for `false`. (This is essentially the same as the considerations on the return values of programs).

Comment: (continued from previous comment). Third reason is that “true that true that A” is the same as “true that A”, “false that false that A” is the same as “false that A”, etc.; so that `true` behaves as the multiplicative 1 and `false` as the multiplicative -1. Which, as powers of -1, means that `true` behaves additionnaly as “even” and `false` as “odd”. Again, it is `true` which deserves to be zero...

Comment: (continued from previous comment). But, obviously, there are also numerous reasons to choose that `true` would be 1 and `false` would be 0! The previous comments juste were to stress that, on the other hand, the common choice is not _obvious_ yet.

Comment: @axiopisty, on you 2nd comment: replacing interpretations of 0 and 1 and && with || will invert the result, but the solution as suggested would work as written, why not: ? - false || ? - false || ? - false would result in all condition parts evaluated.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov - I don't fully understand your comment, but I think you're asking about the application of De Morgan's law. Please see the referenced link, and clarify if you still have a question.

Answer (score 21):

The one fundamental point I find important to understand is this. In bash and in unix shells in general, return values are not boolean. They are integer exit codes. As such, you must evaluate them according to the convention saying 0 means success, and other values mean some error.

With `test`, `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` operators, bash conditions evaluate as true in case of an exit code of 0 (the result of /bin/true). Otherwise they evaluate as false.

Strings are evaluated differently than exit codes:

```
if [ 0 ] ; then echo not null ; fi
if [ $(echo 0) ] ; then echo not null ; fi

if [ -z "" ] ; then echo null ; fi
```

The `(( ))` arithmetic operator interprets 1 and 0 as true and false. But that operator cannot be used as a complete replacement for `test`, `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`. Here is an example showing when the arithmetic operator is useful:

```
for (( counter = 0 ; counter < 10 ; counter ++ )) ; do
  if (( counter % 2 )) ; then echo "odd number $counter" ; fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the braces vs parentheses on true/false

Comment: With regards to the second option, it can also be used like this: `if (( ${some_var:+1} )); then ...`, to convert a variable to `1` if it is set

Answer (score 15):

It's just a convention that a 0 exit code means success.  [EXIT_SUCCESS](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/EXIT_SUCCESS/) will be 0 on almost every modern system.

EDIT:

"why both test 0 and test 1 returns 0(success) ?"

That's a completely different question.  The answer is that passing a single argument to test always results in success unless that argument is the null string ("").  See the [Open Group documentation](https://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

Comment: Then why both `test 0` and `test 1` returns 0(success) ?

Comment: @httpinterpret, `test` doesn't test numerical values.  It tests for whether or not that string is the null string.  `man test` for more information.

Answer (score 12):

Typically programs return zero for success, non-zero for failure; `false` returns 1 because it's a convenient non-zero value, but generally any non-zero value means failure of some sort, and many programs will return different non-zero values to indicate different failure modes

Comment: Downvotes with no explanation (or obvious reason) whatsoever suck and those who do it are lame because they are not helping the community at all.

Answer (score 9):

it's a convention dated back to the early days of Unix.

By convention, all system calls return 0 if succeed, non-zero otherwise, because then different numbers can be used to indicate different reason of failure.

Shells follow this convention, 0 means last command succeeded, non-zero otherwise. Similarly, the non-zero return value comes in handy for output error messages: e.g. 1: "brain dead", 2: "heartless", and so on.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK this come from the C convention that you should return 0 if succeded.
See:

```
man close
```

Most of the C (POSIX) api is build like this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library

Answer (score 3):

Your trying to equate true/false with success/failure.

They are two completely, although subtly at first, different dichotomies!

In shell scripting, there is no such thing as true/false. Shell 'expressions' aren't interpreted as true/false. Rather, shell 'expressions' are processes that either succeed or fail.

Obviously, a process might fail for many reasons. Thus we need a larger set codes to map possible failures to. The positive integers do the trick. On the other hand, if the process succeeds, that means it did exactly what it was supposed to do. Since there is only one way to do that, we only need one code. 0 does the trick.

In C, we are creating a program. In a shell script, we are running a bunch of programs to get something done.

Difference!

Comment: It's confusing. Type 'man ['. It shows The test utility evaluates the expression and, if it evaluates to true, returns a zero (true) exit status; otherwise
     it returns 1 (false).  If there is no expression, test also returns 1 (false).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a good way to remember it is :

- Return codes answer "what's the answer?" true (or other result) or false
- Exit codes answer "what's the problem?" exit code or no problem (0)

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is not tagged for C programming and most answers seem to explain the real reason indirectly, I thought I'll answer, what I hope, a C programmer would find useful.

IMHO, the true source of ambiguity is the C standard. For example, in C11 draft spec's (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) Section "7.22.4.4 The exit function" vs Section "7.18 Boolean type and values <stdbool.h>", EXIT_SUCCESS is zero, which is what programs run from the linux shell cmdline are expected to return on success, whereas, bool true is non-zero (#define'ed to 1, but safer to call it non-zero. Why is that? Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson 's comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009047/4726668 ).

Quoting from C11 draft spec (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

7.22.4.4 The exit function

"

5 Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of status is EXIT_FAILURE, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

"

vs

7.18 Boolean type and values <stdbool.h>

"

3
The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. They are

true

which expands to the integer constant 1,

false

which expands to the integer constant 0, and

_ _bool_true_false_are_defined

which expands to the integer constant 1.

"