# Check Whether a User Exists

Tags: bash

I want to create a script to check whether a user exists. I am using the logic below:

```
# getent passwd test > /dev/null 2&>1
# echo $?
0
# getent passwd test1 > /dev/null 2&>1
# echo $?
2
```

So if the user exists, then we have success, else the user does not exist. I have put above command in the bash script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2&>1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi
```

Now, my script always says that the user exists no matter what:

```
# sh passwd.sh test
yes the user exists
# sh passwd.sh test1
yes the user exists
# sh passwd.sh test2
yes the user exists
```

Why does the above condition always evaluate to be TRUE and say that the user exists?

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After reading all the responses, I found the problem in my script. The problem was the way I was redirecting `getent` output. So I removed all the redirection stuff and made the `getent` line look like this:

```
getent passwd $user > /dev/null
```

Now my script is working fine.

Comment: I think that when you use `$?` you get the return code of the `test` command. See answer below.

Comment: Is that the *exact* code you are running? No "echo" debug statements between the call to `getent` and your `if` statement? That would cause `$?` to check the exit status of `echo`, not your call to `getent`.

Comment: Yeah I think you mean `2>&1` instead of `2&>1`.

Comment: Code works on non-empty input, but if `$1` is not set, the if statement will return true.  From my testing, solution would be to wrap `$1` in double quotes: `getent passwd "$1" > /dev/null 2&>1`.

Comment: Please mark an answer

Comment: @slayedbylucifer The reason your `getent` command does not work is that you have a typo: `2&>1` __is not a valid redirection__.

Answer (score 394):

You can also check user by `id` command.

`id -u name` gives you the id of that user.
If the user doesn't exist, you got command return value (`$?`) `1`.

And as other answers pointed out: if all you want is just to check if the user exists, use `if` with `id` directly, as `if` already checks for the *exit code*. There's no need to fiddle with strings, `[`, `$?` or `$()`:

```bash
if id "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo 'user found'
else
    echo 'user not found'
fi
```

(no need to use `-u` as you're discarding the output anyway)

Also, if you turn this snippet into a function or script, I suggest you also set *your* exit code appropriately:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_exists(){ id "$1" &>/dev/null; } # silent, it just sets the exit code
if user_exists "$1"; code=$?; then  # use the function, save the code
    echo 'user found'
else
    echo 'user not found' >&2  # error messages should go to stderr
fi
exit $code  # set the exit code, ultimately the same set by `id`
```

Comment: That's what I use. See http://superuser.com/questions/336275/find-out-if-user-name-exists

Comment: great answer - just a minor tweak that works nicely...
user_exists=$(id -u user > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)
user_exists=0 if  "user" exists, or 1 if not

Comment: Thats great, id command is available even in yocto images, while getent is not.

Comment: @Pancho I think your variable should be named user_doesnt_exist

Comment: @WillSheppard - the variable as named is correct. Run the command from the bash shell and you will see that it returns 0 if the user exists and 1 if the user doesn't exist. This is as distinct from boolean logic which I assume you are referring to. If you want to get fancy and make the response align that's great, but it's not necessary in order to achieve the distinction. (look at Kent's answer above and you will see my comment simply expands on his answer)

Comment: @Pancho Can you show any example code which uses the variable, where your name makes sense?

Comment: @WillSheppard : echo $(id -u RUBBISHUSER > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)    ....the output is 1 (because RUBBISHUSER doesn't exist) then: echo $(id -u root > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?) ...the output is 0     (because the root user exists). It's really not rocket science, not sure why you don't just open a bash shell and test it yourself. Again, I am not attempting to apply boolean logic here simply extending the original answer.

Comment: @WillSheppard : At a general level boolean handling in bash is in my opinion less than clear  and I typically avoid implicit boolean inferences in my code. The following make interesting reading and interestingly both favour 0 = true and <not 0> = false for bash purposes, and while not de facto, align with the variable name I have used from a boolean perspective also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5431932/3051627 . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933843/why-0-is-true-but-false-is-1-in-the-shell .

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the difference between boolean and return/error code. Your variable name $user_exists implies boolean. Perhaps it should be called $user_check_error :-) #namingishard

Comment: Is it a vanilla linux command? Or does it come with an optional package? I think it's in "coreutils" so it's not universal.

Comment: Thanks to @Pancho's comment I could achieve that, just by sending the error to the void and doing ```validuser(){ [[ -n $(id -u "$1" 2>/dev/null) ]] && echo 1 || echo 0; }```. That, pretty much returns 1 if user exists, or 0 if it does not.

Comment: The status code of the last executed command inside the function is what function returns in bash. So simply put the command inside the function: `user_exists() { id -u $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 }` (this is not a one liner) and use it `if ! user_exists username; then....`

Comment: @muratgozel: your function can perfectly be a one-liner if you just add a `; ` before the closing `}`

Comment: This will be error "permission denied" on create /dev/null.

Answer (score 40):

There's no need to check the exit code explicitly. Try

```
if getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi
```

If that doesn't work, there is something wrong with your `getent`, or you have more users defined than you think.

Answer (score 38):

Why don't you simply use

```
grep -c '^username:' /etc/passwd
```

It will return 1 (since a user has max. 1 entry) if the user exists and 0 if it doesn't.

Comment: This doesn't work if the server is using another system to manage uses such as NIS or LDAP. In this case, you can use `getent passwd | grep -c '^username:'`

Comment: this will return 1 if you have a username, let's say "test1" and want to create a new username called "test".

Comment: @MarinNedea the colon `:` after the username protects against substring matching by matching with the field separator, so the effect you describe won't happen.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` depends on `nsswitch.conf` settings

Answer (score 27):

This is what I ended up doing in a `Freeswitch` bash startup script:

```
# Check if user exists
if ! id -u $FS_USER > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "The user does not exist; execute below commands to crate and try again:"
    echo "  root@sh1:~# adduser --home /usr/local/freeswitch/ --shell /bin/false --no-create-home --ingroup daemon --disabled-password --disabled-login $FS_USER"
    echo "  ..."
    echo "  root@sh1:~# chown freeswitch:daemon /usr/local/freeswitch/ -R"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 27):

By far the simplest solution:

```sh
if id -u "$user" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo 'user exists'
else
    echo 'user missing'
fi
```

The `>/dev/null 2>&1` can be shortened to `&>/dev/null` in Bash, and if you only want to know if a user **does not** exist:

```sh
if ! id -u "$user" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo 'user missing'
fi
```

Comment: The best answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

I was using it in that way:

```
if [ $(getent passwd $user) ] ; then
        echo user $user exists
else
        echo user $user doesn\'t exists
fi
```

Comment: A bad approach. You can get rid of both `[ ]` and `$()` and simply check for `getent`'s _exit code_ directly instead of using its _output_

Answer (score 14):

I suggest to use id command as it tests **valid** user existence wrt passwd file entry which is not necessary means the same:

```
if [ `id -u $USER_TO_CHECK 2>/dev/null || echo -1` -ge 0 ]; then 
echo FOUND
fi
```

Note: 0 is root uid.

Answer (score 7):

[Script to Check whether Linux user exists or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGoVU.png)

## Script To check whether the user exists or not

```
#! /bin/bash
USER_NAME=bakul
cat /etc/passwd | grep ${USER_NAME} >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "User Exists"
else
    echo "User Not Found"
fi
```

Comment: Why use `cat` ?   `grep $USER_NAME /etc/passwd >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Yes Alexx Roche,there is no need to use cat,I have use in order to have better way to visualise the concept for beginner.

Comment: Unneccary use of cat, dependent on nsswitch only being configured to use files.

Comment: This won't work in case the input username matches some other parts of each line in passwd.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer but `finger` also shows more information on user

```
  sudo apt-get finger 
  finger "$username"
```

Comment: OP might not be using Debian.

Answer (score 5):

Using sed:

```
username="alice"
if [ `sed -n "/^$username/p" /etc/passwd` ]
then
    echo "User [$username] already exists"
else
    echo "User [$username] doesn't exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually I cannot reproduce the problem. The script as written in the question works fine, except for the case where $1 is empty.

However, there is a problem in the script related to redirection of `stderr`. Although the two forms `&>` and `>&` exist, in your case you want to use `>&`. You already redirected `stdout`, that's why the form `&>` does not work. You can easily verify it this way:

```
getent /etc/passwd username >/dev/null 2&>1
ls
```

You will see a file named `1` in the current directory. You want to use `2>&1` instead, or use this:

```
getent /etc/passwd username &>/dev/null
```

This also redirects `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

**Warning** Redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` might not be such a good idea. When things go wrong, you will have no clue why.

Answer (score 4):

user infomation is stored in /etc/passwd, so you can use "grep 'usename' /etc/passwd" to check if the username exist.
meanwhile you can use "id" shell command, it will print the user id and group id, if the user does not exist, it will print "no such user" message.

Comment: IT is stored in /etc/passwd IF nsswitch.conf's passwd setting is set to files... This approach breaks if network-based logins are involved...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your shell implementation (e.g. Busybox vs. grown-up) the `[` operator might start a process, changing `$?`.

Try

```
getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2&>1
RES=$?

if [ $RES -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: changing `$?` gives me the same output. This is the bash version: `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Try `if test "$RES" == "0"; then ...`

Comment: `$?` would be expanded before `[` runs, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Instead of testing for the result of the command, you can test the command directly:

`if getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2&>1; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi`

Answer (score 2):

Login to the server.
**grep "username"  /etc/passwd**
This will display the user details if present.

Comment: This will also match any username which contains "username". E.g. "some_username".
You would want to do `if grep -q "^username:" /etc/passwd; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script to check the OS distribution and create User if not exists and do nothing if user exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Detecting OS Ditribution
if [ -f /etc/os-release ]; then
    . /etc/os-release
    OS=$NAME
elif type lsb_release >/dev/null 2>&1; then
OS=$(lsb_release -si)
elif [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then
    . /etc/lsb-release
    OS=$DISTRIB_ID
else
    OS=$(uname -s)
fi

 echo "$OS"

 user=$(cat /etc/passwd | egrep -e ansible | awk -F ":" '{ print $1}')

 #Adding User based on The OS Distribution
 if [[ $OS = *"Red Hat"* ]] || [[ $OS = *"Amazon Linux"* ]] || [[ $OS = *"CentOS"*  
]] && [[ "$user" != "ansible" ]];then
 sudo useradd ansible

elif [ "$OS" =  Ubuntu ] && [ "$user" != "ansible" ]; then
sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" ansible
else
  echo "$user is already exist on $OS"
 exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Create system user `some_user` if it doesn't exist

```
if [[ $(getent passwd some_user) = "" ]]; then
    sudo adduser --no-create-home --force-badname --disabled-login --disabled-password --system some_user
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this nice one line solution

```
getent passwd username > /dev/null 2&>1 && echo yes || echo no
```

and in script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
        getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2&>1 && (echo yes; exit 0) || (echo no; exit 2)
else
        echo "missing username"
        exit -1
fi
```

use:

```
[mrfish@yoda ~]$ ./u_exists.sh root
yes
[mrfish@yoda ~]$ echo $?
0

[mrfish@yoda ~]$ ./u_exists.sh
missing username
[mrfish@yoda ~]$ echo $?
255

[mrfish@yoda ~]$ ./u_exists.sh aaa
no
[mrfish@indegy ~]$ echo $?
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
echo "$PASSWORD" | su -c "cd /" "$USER"
if [ "$?" = "0" ];then
 echo "OK"
else
 echo "Error"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter your Login Name: " loginname
home=`grep -w $loginname /etc/passwd | cut -ef:6 -d:`
if [ $home ]
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Not Exist"
fi
```