# shell_exec check condition useradd

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

I have this phpscript that passes arguments to a .sh script like:

```
$command = shell_exec("sudo ./createclientcert.sh $uniqcertid $number $period $userName $userPass");
```

The username should be checked to see if it not already exists.
Normally when issuing the command via the terminal you' ll get

```
useradd: user 'newusername' already exists
```

How in the sh should i test that condition and abort the script and that it returns something meaningful for the calling php page to respond to?

The sh receives the arguments like:

```
newclient "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"

newclient () {
# Generates the custom client.ovpn
useradd $4    
echo $4:$5 | chpasswd
#some other things but not relevant to the question
}
```

**marked as duplicate and then referring to a solution using something like getent? It's not possible to capture the output useradd generates when the username already exists?**

Comment: make a command $test = shell_exec("ls"); print_r($test); whats the result?

Comment: I really don' t understand what you mean by this suggestion. Shell_exec is working fine and listing a dir is not what i want. In the script the useradd command is issued and it needs to halt if the user already exists and return something meaningful.

Comment: Managed to get it to work with the solution provided by tripleee . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810684/check-whether-a-user-exists  Thnx.