# Script is not switching from root to normal user automatically

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, centos

I am logged in as root than I am running a script with below contents

```
#! /bin/bash
id studentapp if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
then  echo " SKIPPING user creation" 
else useradd studentapp 
echo " User created" 
fi 
cd /home/studentapp
```

Any idea...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you needs `su studentapp` in else block if user was created. `cd` changes working directory. If user was not created - maybe there are no such directory.

[su man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/su1.html)

[cd man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html)

Also it's can be helpful for you:

[check if user exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810684/check-whether-a-user-exists)

[check if direcory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)

**Update**

```
#! /bin/bash
id studentapp
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "user exists" 
else
    useradd studentapp --create-home
    passwd studentapp
    echo "user created" 
fi
su studentapp
cd /home/studentapp
```

Comment: if I go to the consol i can find the user and can switch manually but not via script please find the consol snapshot                                                        
 [root@instance-1 sunnyisgone]# cd /home/studentapp
[root@instance-1 studentapp]#

Comment: try this:
#! /bin/bash
<br/>
id studentapp
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "user exists"
else
    useradd studentapp
    echo "user created" 
    su studentapp
fi
cd /home/studentapp
```

Comment: still same issue. I am using centos vm on google cloud. May be I will try on actuall machine can will get back to you.

Comment: `useradd` command creates a locked user account. You need also unlock the account by issuing the `passwd` command to assign a password.

Comment: the code you gave earlier worked. Thanks. Actually Su studentapp command did the trick. thanks.may be "passwd studentapp" will be need as Ihave not tested the full stack but as of now its working.

Comment: You're welcome =) Also current user home dir stored in `$HOME` variable. So you can change dir with `cd $HOME` or `cd ~`