# Valid input in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, readline

Is there anyway to check for a valid username input in bash? For example, using the `read` command is there a way to ignore or interpret the left arrow input instead of storing `^[[D` in the variable? What other input method can be used in bash other than `read`?

Comment: There are ways to 2 read a line: using character by character, or using [`readline`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). Most modern `read` implementations use the `readline` library, which internally takes care of interpreting left arrow as cursor movement and not literal`^[[D`.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. `read` uses `readline` only when it is passed the `-e` option; as answered by Amadan.

Comment: @anishsane No problem, can you provide more info/documentation on the character by character method?

Comment: For character by character, you will need to implement minimal version of `readline` yourself. Too much pain, if you ask me. Easier would be throwing an error _after_ the user presses enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read -e` will interpret arrows correctly. From `man bash`:

> `-e`
>   If the standard input is coming from a terminal, `readline` (see `READLINE` above) is used to obtain the line.  Readline uses the current (or default, if line editing was not previously active) editing settings.

Checking whether an input string is a valid username is your responsibility, as it has nothing to do with inputting (e.g. see [Check Whether a User Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810684/check-whether-a-user-exists))

Comment: How can we check characters one by one to confirm that no `/` character is entered while using the `read` method?

Comment: "while using the `read` method" - you can't. Again, nothing to do with inputting. You can check it later. See [How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash).