# Expected behaviour of if-then-else condition in bash while checking for any changes in git is opposite when written in a github actions workflow

Tags: git, github, github-actions

If you have a commit statement when there are no changes then it will return an exit code of 1 which will lead to the failure of a GitHub workflow.

As a workaround, I tried to modify the solution from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123674/how-to-git-commit-nothing-without-an-error) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git/2659808#2659808) which is basically to use -

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

On my local bash, it works as expected. When I run `echo "$?"`, the output of 1 or 0 corresponds to what I expect.

Based off of that and this documentation on [setting up environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) in GitHub workflows, I have the following in my workflow file -

```yaml
- name: Check for changes # This blocks behaviour is just the opposite
  run: |
        if git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then
            echo "changes_exist=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        else
            echo "changes_exist=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

- name: Debug changes
  run: |
        echo "${{ env.changes_exist }}"

- name: Commit Datasets # It is true whenever there are NO changes and false whenever there are changes, so whenever there are changes it is just skipped due to the "if" condition
  if: env.changes_exist == 'true'
  run: |
        git commit -m "updating datasets"
        git push
```

However, whenever there are changes to be committed or tracked, the environment variable **changes_exist** is `false` and vice-versa.

This is just the opposite of what I am expecting.

As a workaround till I figure this out I use the following which works perfectly in the worker -

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "updating datasets"
```

Any idea why the above works whereas using `if - then - else` the behavior opposite to what it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123841/6309) which shows:

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m 'bla'
```

Which means, there are changes if `! git diff`: the commit part is executed only if the `git diff` part is false, fails, different from 0.
It could be written as:

```
if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then git commit -m 'bla'; fi
```

In other words, in your case:

```bash
# Equivalent approach using an if statement with negation
if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then
    echo "changes_exist=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
else
    echo "changes_exist=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
fi
```

Comment: I was thinking that 0 refers to False and 1 or any other number refers to True. Since, if any command fails, it would have an exit code > 0, I thought I was doing `if failed`; `then <there are changes to commit>...`
Pardon me, but I don't get why I need to add `!` before the command.

Comment: @jar `!` means "check if not true". True is 0. False is one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933877/6309

Comment: the "or"/`||` can get a little confusing - the `if` stops evaluating its parts when it finds the first `true` value, so it only gets to the part _after_ the `||` when the first part is false/empty. so, `git diff-index --quiet HEAD` in the `||` statement needs to be 0/false to get to the `git commit` or "when the first part is _not true_, do the commit"

Comment: @Sandra True. Thank you for your feedback. I have rewritten the last part to make that clearer.